# Problema con flutter run

Tags: flutter, sqlite

Hasta ayer, mi `app` corría bien, sin ningún problema. Hoy cuando quise correrla otra vez me salió un error que no tengo (no tomé pantallazo) era acerca de una dependencia que estaba usando. El caso es que tratando de organizarlo actualicé `flutter` a la versión 2.0.2 y siguieron apareciendo errores.

Como ultimo recurso después de buscar mucho en internet, decidí borrar el `sdk` de `flutter` con las variables de entorno y volver a instalarlo. Cuando hice eso, el error que sale cuando ejecuto flutter run es el siguiente:

```
    Pointer<Void>,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:135:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void>,
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:135:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void>,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:135:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void>,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:136:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void>,
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:136:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void>,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:136:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void>,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:137:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void>,
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:137:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void>,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:137:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void>,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:138:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void>);
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:138:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void>);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:138:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void>);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:140:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3> db,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:140:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3> db,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:141:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<char> zFunctionName,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:141:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<char> zFunctionName,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:144:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void> pApp,
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:144:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void> pApp,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:144:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void> pApp,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:145:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void> xFunc,
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:145:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void> xFunc,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:145:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void> xFunc,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:146:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void> xStep,
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:146:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void> xStep,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:146:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void> xStep,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:147:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void> xFinal,
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:147:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void> xFinal,
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:147:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void> xFinal,
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:148:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void> xDestroy);
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:148:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void> xDestroy);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:148:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void> xDestroy);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:149:53: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
typedef _sqlite3_aggregate_context_native = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                                    ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:149:45: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
typedef _sqlite3_aggregate_context_native = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                            ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:149:45: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
typedef _sqlite3_aggregate_context_native = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                            ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:150:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Int32);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:150:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Int32);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:150:31: Error: Type 'Int32' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Int32);
                              ^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:151:50: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
typedef sqlite3_aggregate_context_dart = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                                 ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:151:42: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
typedef sqlite3_aggregate_context_dart = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                         ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:151:42: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
typedef sqlite3_aggregate_context_dart = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                         ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:152:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx, int nBytes);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:152:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx, int nBytes);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:153:45: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
typedef _sqlite3_user_data_native = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:153:37: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
typedef _sqlite3_user_data_native = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:153:37: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
typedef _sqlite3_user_data_native = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:154:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:154:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:155:42: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
typedef sqlite3_user_data_dart = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                         ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:155:34: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
typedef sqlite3_user_data_dart = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                 ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:155:34: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
typedef sqlite3_user_data_dart = Pointer<Void> Function(
                                 ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:156:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:156:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:157:41: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
typedef _sqlite3_result_blob64_native = Void Function(
                                        ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:39: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
                                      ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:31: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
                              ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:31: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
                              ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:46: Error: Type 'Uint64' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
                                             ^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:62: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
                                                             ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:54: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
                                                     ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:158:54: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<Void>, Uint64, Pointer<Void>);
                                                     ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:159:52: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
typedef sqlite3_result_blob64_dart = void Function(Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx,
                                                   ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:159:52: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
typedef sqlite3_result_blob64_dart = void Function(Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx,
                                                   ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:160:13: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void> data, int length, Pointer<Void> destructor);
            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:160:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void> data, int length, Pointer<Void> destructor);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:160:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void> data, int length, Pointer<Void> destructor);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:160:45: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
    Pointer<Void> data, int length, Pointer<Void> destructor);
                                            ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:160:37: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<Void> data, int length, Pointer<Void> destructor);
                                    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:160:37: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<Void> data, int length, Pointer<Void> destructor);
                                    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:161:41: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
typedef _sqlite3_result_double_native = Void Function(
                                        ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:162:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Double);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:162:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Double);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:162:31: Error: Type 'Double' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Double);
                              ^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:164:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx, double result);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:164:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx, double result);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:165:40: Error: Type 'Void' not found.
typedef _sqlite3_result_error_native = Void Function(
                                       ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:166:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<char>, Int32);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:166:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<char>, Int32);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:166:31: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<char>, Int32);
                              ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:166:31: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<char>, Int32);
                              ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:166:46: Error: Type 'Int32' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context>, Pointer<char>, Int32);
                                             ^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:168:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx, Pointer<char> msg, int length);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:168:5: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx, Pointer<char> msg, int length);
    ^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:168:35: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx, Pointer<char> msg, int length);
                                  ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:168:35: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
    Pointer<sqlite3_context> ctx, Pointer<char> msg, int length);
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:33:29: Error: Type 'Int32' not found.
typedef WinHeapFreeNative = Int32 Function(
                            ^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:34:5: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer heap, Uint32 flags, Pointer memory);
    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:34:19: Error: Type 'Uint32' not found.
    Pointer heap, Uint32 flags, Pointer memory);
                  ^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:34:33: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
    Pointer heap, Uint32 flags, Pointer memory);
                                ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:35:36: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
typedef WinHeapFree = int Function(Pointer heap, int flags, Pointer memory);
                                   ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:35:61: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
typedef WinHeapFree = int Function(Pointer heap, int flags, Pointer memory);
                                                            ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:46:1: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
Pointer<T> allocate<T extends NativeType>({int count = 1}) {
^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:46:1: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
Pointer<T> allocate<T extends NativeType>({int count = 1}) {
^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:46:31: Error: Type 'NativeType' not found.
Pointer<T> allocate<T extends NativeType>({int count = 1}) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:70:11: Error: Type 'Pointer' not found.
void free(Pointer pointer) {
          ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/moor-3.4.0/lib/src/ffi/database_tracker.dart:64:21: Error: The getter 'Pointer' isn't defined for the
class 'DatabaseTracker'.
 - 'DatabaseTracker' is from 'package:moor/src/ffi/database_tracker.dart'
 ('../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/moor-3.4.0/lib/src/ffi/database_tracker.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Pointer'.
        final ptr = Pointer.fromAddress(row.columnAt(0) as int);
                    ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/api/sqlite3.dart:14:17: Error: 'Pointer' isn't a type.
  final Pointer<Pointer<char>> _sqlite3_temp_directory;
                ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/api/sqlite3.dart:14:9: Error: 'Pointer' isn't a type.
  final Pointer<Pointer<char>> _sqlite3_temp_directory;
        ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/api/sqlite3.dart:20:13: Error: 'DynamicLibrary' isn't a type.
  Sqlite3._(DynamicLibrary library)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/api/sqlite3.dart:64:24: Error: 'Pointer' isn't a type.
  Database fromPointer(Pointer<void> database) {
                       ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/ffi.dart:20:26: Error: 'Uint8' isn't a type.
    final asBytes = cast<Uint8>();
                         ^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/ffi.dart:31:22: Error: 'Uint8' isn't a type.
        .decode(cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(resolvedLength).buffer.asUint8List());
                     ^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/ffi.dart:40:25: Error: 'Uint8' isn't a type.
    list.setAll(0, cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(length));
                        ^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/ffi.dart:120:17: Error: 'Pointer' isn't a type.
  final Pointer<Pointer<sqlite3_value>> argArray;
                ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/ffi.dart:120:9: Error: 'Pointer' isn't a type.
  final Pointer<Pointer<sqlite3_value>> argArray;
        ^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/impl/database.dart:6:9: Error: 'Pointer' isn't a type.
  final Pointer<sqlite3> _handle;
        ^^^^^^^
```

Y así un montón que no alcancé a poner acá, todos apuntan a esta ruta: /Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org

Agradecería inmensamente cualquier ayuda.

Comment: prueba realizando `flutter clean` y luego `flutter pub get`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia. Creo que el problema era que estaba escogiendo chrome como emulador, cuando lo cambié ya salió otro error diferente

Comment: si persiste tu problema con el proyecto, por favor actualiza tu pregunta, agregando nueva información o editando completamente la pregunta, si le diste solución de alguna forma, por favor publica tu resultado como respuesta para que otros puedan darle solución al mismo problema o similar, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al final, me di cuenta que estaba intentando correr en el emulador web de chrome, para lo que se requería cambiar de canal así:
`flutter channel beta`
Pero eso no era lo que necesitaba, así que lo que hice fue cambiar de emulador a un AVD de Android studio